# NodeJS complains that an object is undefined if it's been set in an if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, scope, declaration

I have the following code:

```
var inNode = function () {
  return (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) ? true : false;
};

if (inNode()) {
  global.TestObj = { 'test' : 'hello!' };
} else {
  var TestObj = { 'test' : 'hello!' };
}

console.log(TestObj);
```

TestObj will return as undefined.

I understand in other programming languages that the compiler would complain if you declared a variable inside an if statement and then tried to call it. I didn't think this was the case in Javascript - and if so, where's the error message?!

Cheers!

Comment: You have a scoping problem, the `var` is defined and accessible only within the `else` block in that case

Comment: @jeremy It's not. Read about [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting).

Comment: @jeremy - I'm running inside nodejs, so in any case that never gets set, it should be set to the global scope object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due the concept of [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) in JavaScript, all variable declarations are moved to the top of the scope, so your code is actually:

```
var inNode = function () {
  return (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) ? true : false;
};
var TestObj;

if (inNode()) {
  global.TestObj = { 'test' : 'hello!' };
} else {
  TestObj = { 'test' : 'hello!' };
}

console.log(TestObj);
```

Which means that it **is** defined, but it only has a value if the `else` block is executed. Otherwise it's `undefined`.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo In this case, `TestObj` is accessible no matters what `inNode()` returns. The point is that `TestObj` will only point to `global.TestObj` if no local `TestObj` variable was declared. Since it is declared, then it always reference the local variable.